# What is the analytic continuation of a multifactorial?

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, factorial

> The $\Gamma$ function is the analytic continuation of the factorial function.  Is there a similar analog for multifactorials?

I am particularly interested in the double factorial.  All Google has given me is the following formula relating the $\Gamma$ function to the double factorial for half integer values: $$\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}$$ But I want to double factorial nonintegers, so this is not really helpful.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on "factorial" has some answers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Alternative_extension_of_the_double_factorial

Comment: "The Γ function is the analytic continuation of the factorial function." This makes it sound as if $\Gamma$ is the unique analytic function that interpolates factorial, but this is far from being the case. What criteria are you using to single out $\Gamma$ from all possible analytic interpolants? (Or maybe you mean something different.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why is this not helpful?  If you write the identity as $$(2n-1)!! = \frac{\Gamma(n + \frac{1}{2}) 2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$  and then let $n = (x+1)/2$ you get $$x!! = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{x+2}{2}) 2^{(x+1)/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$ The right side is now defined for any complex $x$ as long as the argument for the Gamma function is defined.

Answer (score 6):

Despite this being a 10-year old post, it does come up when searching "double factorial analytic continuation", so I thought I'd expand on Ted's answer. (I'm new to StackExchange so hopefully I don't do anything wrong!)

The equation given by Ted (and Brad's linked Wikipedia page) *does* work for any complex input $x$, but it is specifically based on the double-factorial definition that starts with an *odd integer*:
$$(2n - 1)!! = \prod_{k=1}^n (2k - 1) = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdots (2n - 1)$$
However, it seems quite common to extend the definition to even numbers like so:
$$(2n)!! = \prod_{k=1}^n (2k) = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)$$

It turns out that the analytic continuation for the 'even version' *is different* to the 'odd version'! I'll denote the odd version $F_-(x)$ and the even version $F_+(x)$.

The formula for $F_+(x)$ is actually quite simple to derive. We simply notice that the even double-factorial is a normal factorial except with *each term doubled*:
$$(2n)!! = \prod_{k=1}^n 2k = 2(1) \cdot 2(2) \cdot 2(3) \cdots 2(n) = 2^n \cdot n!$$
Then to define $F_+$ we just set $2n = x$ and substitute in the gamma function:
$$F_+(x) = 2^{x/2} \cdot \Gamma \left(\frac x2 + 1 \right)$$
Recalling the formula for $F_-(x)$:
$$F_-(x) = \frac{2^{(x+1)/2}}{\sqrt \pi} \cdot \Gamma \left( \frac{x + 2}{2} \right)$$
We can then find the relationship between $F_+$ and $F_-$:
$$F_+(x) = F_-(x) \cdot \sqrt{\pi / 2}$$
So one is a scaled version of the other!

It should be possible to define a more complicated function that interpolates between these two cases -- matching $F_+$ for even integers and $F_-$ for odd ones -- but at that point I expect it would be difficult to call any particular choice of interpolation 'the most intuitive'.

For 'higher-order' multifactorials, I expect they require more functions -- $3$ for $x!!!$, $4$ for $x!!!!$, etc. -- though I have not yet tried to confirm this.

Comment: For anyone curious, here is a Desmos plot of these functions together with one choice of interpolant $F(x) = \sin^2(\pi x/2) F_-(x) + \cos^2(\pi x/2) F_+(x)$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/od1qhvjhv7

Comment: You're correct in your final comment about multifactorials, in general one needs to interpolate $k$ functions for $x(!^k)$. I worked it out in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488791/define-the-triple-factorial-n-as-a-continuous-function-for-n-in-mathbb/3488935#3488935).