# Is there a $k$ such that $a_n=\frac{n^k!}{(n^k!!)^2}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory

Lately I have been playing around with the sequence $$a_n(k) := \frac{n^k!}{(n^k!!)^2}.$$

For $k=1$, it does not look much like it converges.[image: k=1]

I don't know $k=2$ it converges, but it doesn't really look like it.

[image: k=2]

  1.

---

> <strike>**Question 1.** Can we prove that for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_n=\frac{n^k!}{(n^k!!)^2}$ converges?  If not can we prove why not?</strike>  Thanks mercio.

Also, inspired by my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291890/12952), I thought it would be interesting to talk about an extension of $k$ to the complex numbers. $$\frac{n^k!}{(n^k!!)^2}\rightarrow \frac{2^{-1-n^k} \pi  \Gamma\left(n^k\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{n^k}{2}\right)^2}$$

> **Question 2.** Where does this extension of $a_n$ to the complex plane converge?  What are its zeroes like?

*EDIT*: By the way, this is a plot of $a_6(k)$ for $-2\leq \Re(k) \leq 2$, $-2\leq \Im(k) \leq 2$:

[image: a6]

(Here, the height is $|a_6(k)|$ and the color is $\operatorname{Arg}{a_6(k)}$.)

It seems that the "stripes" squeeze in as $n$ increases but I don't know what happens in the limit, or if there is a simple explanation of what happens.

Comment: No doubt $n!!$ means [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Double_factorial), the product of positive integers of the same parity as $n$ up to $n$

Comment: @mixedmath some people uses $n!!$ to denote the product $n(n-2)(n-4)...$

Comment: @achille: Ah! I didn't know! Thank you for that.

Comment: If it is true for any positive integer $k$ then it is true for all such $k$.  The graphs suggest to me that there is exponential convergence to $0$.

Comment: Do you know [stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)? I think stirling approximation is adequate to estimate this limit.

Comment: FYI, you can plug this into Mathematica and it gives the result.

Comment: @amr For question $2$? What did you use?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber nah, for the first one. the second one appears to be intractable as a limit to Mathematica 8, though there is a nonzero chance version 9 may be able to handle it. [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^%28-1-n^z%29+Pi+gamma%28n^z%29%2Fgamma%281%2B%28n^z%29%2F2%29^2) or [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+2^%28-1-n^z%29+Pi+gamma%28n^z%29%2Fgamma%281%2B%28n^z%29%2F2%29^2) might be useful in case you haven't seen them

Comment: @amr That first one is really nice.  I made some ABS/ARG plots also and they were pretty enlightening.  I think there's gonna end up being convergence only on one half plane but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 11):

As Henry suggests, the sequence always converges to $0$ :

Expanding the factorials, you get :

$(2n)!/(2n)!!^2 = \prod_{k=1}^n (2k-1)/(2k) = \prod_{k-1}^n (1-1/(2k))$
$(2n+1)!/(2n+1)!!^2 = \prod_{k=1}^n (2k)/(2k+1) = \prod_{k-1}^n (1-1/(2k+1))$

In both cases, their logarithm diverges to $- \infty$ (because the harmonic series diverges), and thus the sequence $(n!/n!!^2)$ converges to $0$ (and it should be a $O(n^{-1/2})$ while doing so)