# Asymptotic Approximations for Higher-Order Factorials (e.g. triple factorial) and the Gamma Function

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, approximation, factorial, gamma-function

I recently found the asymptotic expansion for $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}$ to be $\sqrt{\pi n}$ by simplifying the double factorials and applying Stirling's formula.
However, I was unable to find an asymptotic approximation for  $\frac{(3n)!!!}{(3n-1)!!!}$ since triple factorials are much more difficult to work with.

I used the following [multifactorial extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488791/define-the-triple-factorial-n-as-a-continuous-function-for-n-in-mathbb) to derive an asymptotic formula for $\frac{(3n)!!!}{(3n-1)!!!}$, however, I was unable to simplify this expression well enough to derive its asymptotic approximation.

Are there any well-known formulas for the $n^{th}$ factorial? Ideally, I want to find asymptotical approximations for $\frac{(kn)!_k}{(kn-1)!_k}$, where $!_k$ denotes the $k^{th}$ factorial. Any insight or alternative formulas for my calculations would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I am assuming n is a positive integer for these calculations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Replying to the bot, I'm specifically interested in finding asymptotic approximations for higher order factorials (triple factorial, quadruple factorial, etc) so I can compute the asymptotic approximation for the quotient of higher order factorials of x and x-1

Comment: Write down your precise definitions of these objects. Are you interested in complex values or just positive integer arguments? And use MathJax to format your equations!

Comment: @Gary I am interesting in positive integers for these calculations. Also, I reformatted & updated my problem so hopefully that makes it more clear!

Comment: Btw, the asymptotics for the double factorial ratio is $1/\sqrt{\pi n}$ and not $\sqrt{\pi n}$.

Comment: @Gary my mistake, I meant to have $(kn)!_k$ in the numerator. However, that would just yield the reciprocal of your result if I'm not mistaken, so I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the explicit formulae given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3488935) together with the [known asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E13) for the ratio of two gamma functions to deduce
$$
\frac{{(3n)!!!}}{{(3n-1)!!!}} = \frac{\Gamma\! \left( {\frac{2}{3}} \right)\Gamma (n + 1)}{{\Gamma\! \left( {n + \frac{2}{3}} \right)}} \sim  \Gamma\! \left( {\tfrac{2}{3}} \right)n^{1/3} \left( {1 +\frac{1}{{9n}} - \frac{10}{{2187n^3 }} +\frac{11}{19683n^4}+  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. The method for higher analogues is similar.

Comment: This is great! I tried applying this approach to $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}$ and it approximated $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) n^{1/2}$, which similarly equals $\sqrt{\pi n}$

Comment: @Bryce I adjusted the answer to your modified question.